# Ubuntu 19 Disco Dingo System Settings don't launch

Tags: system-settings, unity-control-center

Instead, I get the Activity Log Manager, and cannot seem to open Settings regardless. 
This has never happened before. Tried removing and reinstalling the Unity Control Center, and no go. 
Does anyone know what could be done?
Thanks guys
[image]

Comment: are you sure you have unity as desktop?  `env | grep -i session` please.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having issues like this too and it goes away for a little while when I reset my desktop to default.

dconf reset -f /

Regular settings won't open whether from dashbar or application panel, there is a KDE setting application that I did not download (and keeps reappearing). It's most annoying as it messes with screen mirroring. First I've seen of a similar complaint though